# Two images side by side with another two images in the same column

Tags: graphics

I am trying to achieve something like this (with individual subcaption for each image):

[image]

I would like to know how to be able to add an arbitrary number of images A on the left (or right) of the two images-colum. I did not understood how latex works in placing images:

```
    \newsavebox{\measurebox}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{subfig}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \sbox{\measurebox}{%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\textwidth}
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figA}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{images/bosquet_1.png}}
    \end{minipage}}
    \usebox{\measurebox}\qquad
    \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figB}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        
        \vfill
        
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figC}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
    \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you put into the first `minipage` will end up in the "left column", separate two images that you want to appear on top of each other by an empty line. If you place multiple images in the first minipage, all of them will be taken into account by the savebox. All images you place in the second minipage will appear in the "right column". If you want them to be evenly spread, separate them by empty lines and `\vfill`.

Two further examples with different amounts of images per column could look like the following:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \newsavebox{\measurebox}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \sbox{\measurebox}{%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\textwidth}
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figA}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
            
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figB}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=6cm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}}
    \usebox{\measurebox}\qquad
    \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figC}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
        
        \vfill
        
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figD}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
        
        \vfill
        
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figE}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
        
        \vfill
        
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figF}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image}}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{my caption. (\subref{fig:figA}) is .... (\subref{fig:figB}) is .... (\subref{fig:figC}) is .... }
    \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \sbox{\measurebox}{%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\textwidth}
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figA}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
            
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figB}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
            
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figC}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}}
    \usebox{\measurebox}\qquad
    \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figD}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}}
        
        \vfill
        
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figE}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{my caption. (\subref{fig:figA}) is .... (\subref{fig:figB}) is .... (\subref{fig:figC}) is .... }
    \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Side notes:

For your actual images, make sure, you only use `width=..` or `height=...`(or at least add `keepaspectratio`), otherwise the images will get distorted, as you can see from my two examples.

Make sure the contents in the first minipage are taller than the contents in teh second minipage. Otherwise you will see overlaps.

In order to add more information about each subfigure inside of the main caption of the figure, you can use `\subref` as I did in my example code. I also suggest using more descriptive keys for the labels. Identifying images will then be a lot easier, especially if you later on decide to remove/add an image. (If you do so, `fig:figB` would not necessarily correspond to the sufigure with the caption (b))

---

Update regarding the request in the comments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \newsavebox{\measurebox}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \sbox{\measurebox}{%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figA}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}}
    \usebox{\measurebox}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\textwidth}
            \subfloat
            []
            {\label{fig:figA2}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figB}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
        
        \vfill
        
        \subfloat
        []
        {\label{fig:figC}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
    \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for youe explanation. Actually I would like to add another image of the size of A next to the images already there.

Comment: A sketch of the desired output would be really helpful here. Would you add one to your question?

Comment: Sure! I did it, thanks :D

Comment: Thanks for adding the image. What about the subcaptions? Should both "example-image-a" get an individual subcaption or a shared one?  Here are two examples of individual or shared subcaptions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVZEE.png

Comment: they should get and individual one each!

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. You can use three minipages for this tast instead of just two.