# more customized subfloat layout with spanned columns or rows

Tags: floats, subfloats, subfig

I can have a 2x2 array of figures with the following snippet:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \subfloat[f1]{%
                {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f1.pdf}}
                }%
    \subfloat[f2]{%
                {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f2.pdf}}
                }%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[f3]{%
                {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f3.pdf}}
                }%
    \subfloat[f4]{%
                {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f4.pdf}}
                }%
    \caption[layout]{layout}%
    \label{fig:layout}%
\end{figure*}
```

However, if I want to add another figure on the right side of these 4 figures like the following image, I am not sure what to do.

[image]

So far I tried:

```
\begin{figure*}
        \centering
\subfloat{
        \subfloat[f1]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f1.pdf}}
                    }%
        \subfloat[f2]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f2.pdf}}
                    }%
        \qquad
        \subfloat[f3]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f3.pdf}}
                    }%
        \subfloat[f4]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f4.pdf}}
                    }%
}
        \subfloat[f5]{%
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{./figures/f5.pdf}}
    \caption[layout]{layout}%
    \label{fig:layout}%
\end{figure*}
```

but the result wasn't as I expected.

Does anyone know a simple modification to this?

Comment: Probably my answer to a simliar question can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579231/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `tabular` to better control the content of rows and columns. (First example). It requires adjusting the position of the first row to align the top of the figures.

The second option is to use the `nicematrix` package and use the command `\Block`  to define a cell block (2 rows, 1 column here) and center the content without the need for additional settings.

There is also  the option of `minipages` as suggested by leandriis.

All of them are easily generalizable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
%% The example images are provided by the graphicx package, which is loaded by nicematrix
%\usepackage{graphicx}
  
\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth ]{example-image-a}   &\\[-0.31\linewidth] %adjust to level the tops
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.61\linewidth]{example-image-c} 
\end{tabular}
\caption[layout]{layout with tabular}%
\label{fig:layout1}%
\end{table}

\vspace{50pt}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth ]{example-image-a}   & 
\Block{2-1}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.61\linewidth]{example-image-c}}  \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}    & 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption[layout]{layout with nicematrix}%
\label{fig:layout2}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```