# Trying to place an image vertically above another in a two column document in latex

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption

I am trying to get one tall image on the left with two smaller images next to it, one on top of the other. This is my code so far:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

   \subcaptionbox*{First subfigure}[.45\linewidth]
{%

   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,]{figure 1/figure1b.png}
  }

  \hfill
  
\subcaptionbox*{Second subfigure}[.45\linewidth]{%
    
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure 1/figure1.png}}
    
\hfill
   
 \subcaptionbox* {Third subfigure}[.45\linewidth]{
       
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, right]{figure 1/Lumo of 2 unpaired e- carbene.png}}%
```

But it produces this :

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579231/134144 may serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the primitive command `\valign`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\valign{%
  #\cr
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox*{First subfigure}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.8\linewidth]{example-image}%
  }}\cr\noalign{\hfill}
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox*{Second subfigure}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
  }}
  \vfill
  \hbox{\subcaptionbox* {Third subfigure}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
  }}\cr
}

\caption{Three images}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

For the figure on the left I used `height` in order to emulate your images, of course you won't specify it.

As long as your images on the right fit in the vertical size of the image on the left, this will do as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to insert images in table. Using `tabularray` package the possible MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
%
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c] X[c]},
             measure = vbox,
             vspan=even
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c} 
    \subfloat[First sub figure]%
        {
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=1.65\linewidth] {example-image-a}
        }
    &   \subfloat[Second sub figure]%
            {
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            }\\
    &   \subfloat[Second sub figure]%
            {
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            }
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Three images}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]